# Update user detail in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have written code by own knowledge for update user details using Codeignitor but nothing happen when i click update button user account page. Can anyone help me to find the problem and solution to solve by using folowing below my code:

Controller:

```
public function update_userdetail() {
    // Load form helper and validation library
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    // Update field validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|is_unique[users.username]', array('is_unique' => 'This username already exists.'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]', array('is_unique' => 'This email already exists.'));
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        redirect('user/account');
    } else {
        // Set variable from Form
        $user_id    =   $this->input->post('user_id');
        $username   =   $this->input->post('username');
        $email      =   $this->input->post('email');
        if($this->user_model->update_user($user_id, $username, $email)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('notice','<div class="success">Your details updated Successfully!</div>');
            redirect('user/account');
        } else {    
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="error">Problem with update your detail!</div>');
            redirect('user/account');
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function update_user($username, $email, $user_id) {  
        $data = array (
            'username'   => $username,
            'email'      => $email,
            'updated_at' => date('Y-m-j H:i:s'),
        );
        $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
        $this->db->update('users', $data);
        return; 
    }
```

Form:

```
<?php 
    $username   = ($this->session->userdata['username']);
    $email      = ($this->session->userdata['email']);
    $user_id    = ($this->session->userdata['user_id']);
    ?>
    <h3>Update detail</h3>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
    <?php echo form_open(); ?>
    <input type="text" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
    <small class="error-text"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></small>
    </div> 
    <div>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
    <small class="error-text"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></small>
    </div>
    <div><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?></div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: cehck this link : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: ist of all check `print_r($_POST);` getting values or not?

Comment: @PathikVejani Yes, i did but can't able to find where is the problem :(

Comment: change this `<?php echo form_open(); ?>` to `<?php echo form_open(controller/update_userdetail); ?>` @RahamathullahMohamedKasim

Comment: what is controller name? @RahamathullahMohamedKasim

Comment: @PathikVejani User.php but i tried your form open but same problem with no result or error

Comment: @devpro getting 'Array ( )'

Comment: it means, u r not getting anything from your HTML form

Comment: use `$this->load->helper('form');` in your controller constructor or use this helper into your autoload.php file

Comment: Check the code, i am already using `$this->load->helper('form');` and yes coming emptry array.

Comment: no, i am not talking about `update_userdetail()` function, i am talking about controller constructor, or add in autoload.php

Comment: `form` helper should be autoloaded

Comment: open `autoload.php` from `config` folder and do this: **$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','html','language','cookie');**

Comment: @devpro You mean the following ? `public function __construct() {
 
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('user_model');
  $this->load->helper('form');
 }`

Comment: yes offcourse, two solution one is this, and second one is autoload.php

Comment: @devpro
I have enabled both but not working actually no form action is happening, don't know the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was on model and it should be following:

```
public function update_user($user_id, $username, $email) //Change effect
{  
        $data = array (
            'username'   => $username,
            'email'      => $email,
            'updated_at' => date('Y-m-j H:i:s'),
        );
        $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
        return $this->db->update('users', $data); //Change effect
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load form helper class from `autoload.php` file as:

**Location: (application/config/autoload.php)**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

And the second solution is, to load your Form Helper in Controller's constructor.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
}
```

Comment: @RahamathullahMohamedKasim: did you try it with simple html form? like `<form method="post">` instead of `<?php echo form_open(); ?>`

Comment: on error_reporting, maybe memory issue. @RahamathullahMohamedKasim

Comment: no, i posted answer. Thank you so much for your effert